# Why are my variables inside HTML tags not showing up?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to make a component to show random products from an array. When I `console log props.products[random].company` or any other attribute, I can see them in the console. But when I put them inside HTML tags, it doesn't render.

The length of the array is 14. There are random numbers being rendered, but they're greater than 14 too sometimes, and seem to be in sequence for some reason.

This is the component's file :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getProducts } from '../../../actions/productsActions';
export const ProductSm = (props) => {
  console.log(props.products);

  return (
    <div>
      {
       props.products.length >= 1 && setInterval(() => {
  
          let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*props.products.length);
          console.log(random);
          console.log(props.products[random].company);
          return (
                <div>
                  <p>{props.products[random].company}</p>
                  <p>{props.products[random].name}</p>
                  <img src={`http://localhost:5000/${props.products[random].productImage}`} alt="productImage"/>
                </div>)
        }, 5000)
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.products.products,
  loading: state.products.products
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getProducts})(ProductSm);
```

And this is the component containing ProductSm.js :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getProducts, setLoading } from '../../../actions/productsActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Home.css';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import ProductSm from './ProductSm';
export const Home = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setLoading();
    props.getProducts();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(props.products);
    console.log(props.loading);
  }, []); 
  if(props.loading) {
    return <Loading />
  }
  else {
    
  return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="home">
          <div className="group-1">
            <div className="branding">
              <div className="brandName">
                The
                <br/>
                Sole
                <br/>
                Store
              </div>
              <div>
                  <p>The finest designs and fits.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="viewProducts">
              <div>
                <p>
                  Check out our latest and greatest models
                </p>
                <Link className="productsBtn" to="/shoes">GO <i className="fas fa-arrow-right"/></Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="group-2">
            <div className="products">
                <ProductSm />
                <ProductSm />
                <ProductSm />
                <ProductSm />
            </div>
            <div className="something"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}
}
Home.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.products.products,
  loading: state.products.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getProducts, setLoading})(Home);
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thank you[image]

[image]

Comment: I stopped reading as soon as I hit `setInterval` in the return of the first snippet. You can't asynchronously render JSX and react render functions should be pure, i.e. without side-effects like setting timeouts and console logs. You don't see the UI update because you never update state or props.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'll implement setState for random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the code that should work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getProducts } from "../../../actions/productsActions";

export const ProductSm = (props) => {
  const [randomProductIndex, setRandomProductIndex] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.products.length >= 1) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * props.products.length);

        setRandomProductIndex(randomIndex);
      }, 5000);

      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [props.products.length]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.products[randomProductIndex].company}</p>
      <p>{props.products[randomProductIndex].name}</p>
      <img
        src={`http://localhost:5000/${props.products[randomProductIndex].productImage}`}
        alt="productImage"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.products.products,
  loading: state.products.products,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts })(ProductSm);
```

### Explanation:

The error is basically in this line:

```
props.products.length >= 1 && setInterval(...)
```

If the left side of the `&&` operator is true, it will return whatever the right side returns. The `setInterval`-method returns a number that will identify this interval, so you can cancel it with `clearInterval(number)`. Returning something from within the `setInterval` doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently returning the result of `setInterval`, not any JSX:

```
return (
    <div>
      {
       props.products.length >= 1 && setInterval(() => {
```

The function passed to `setInterval` is called asynchronously (after 5000ms in this case).  So, you aren't, in fact, returning anything to render.

Instead, you probably want to track the random number as state, and trigger a re-render every 5000ms

Comment: It does return something to render, the numbers shown in the squares, which are the IDs of the intervals.

Comment: Thank you! I used setInverval on the random state inside useEffect